# Out of memory when chaging font dynamically in C#

Tags: c#

I try to list all available fonts in ComboBox, but with font names printed in a given font family. It works, but it also crashes from time to time, with message "Out of memory", when I move mouse over opened ComboBox. Without changing fonts, it doesn't crash. Why the message occurs? And what to do to make it works?

Code:

```
private void tbrFontNameComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ?
                        new SolidBrush(Color.Blue) : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor);
        Brush tBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);

        g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
        Font font = new Font(tbrFontName.Items[e.Index].ToString(), 10);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(tbrFontName.Items[e.Index].ToString(), font,
                    tBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        brush.Dispose();
        tBrush.Dispose();
        font.Dispose();
    }
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

Comment: It's good that you are calling `Dispose` though `using() { ... }` would be better

Comment: Please share a [mcve].